# Converting factors into numeric format with signs in R

Tags: r

Let, I have such a dataframe(df) where each elements are factors:

```
df
---
+100.5
+120.2
-30.0
+75.0
-600.3
```

How can I convert df into a numric df using R? I ill be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RHertel, I get such an Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion from factors to numerical values is sometimes complicated, and I think that it is usually necessary to convert the factors first into characters, and then into numerical values.

This should work:

```
df_n <- as.data.frame(as.numeric(as.character(df[,1])))
colnames(df_n) <- "df_n"

head(df_n)
#    df_n
#1  100.5
#2  120.2
#3  -30.0
#4   75.0
#5 -600.3
class(df_n[,1])
#[1] "numeric"
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(df = structure(c(4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L), 
     .Label = c("-600.3", "-30", "75", "100.5", "120.2"), 
      class = "factor")), .Names = "df", 
      row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Hope this helps.